# How to set a default value for a dependent field based on the answer of the parent with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, nested

I'm trying to have 4 sub fields, billing code, channel, subject code and name, autopopulate certain values based on the answer of their parent field, Event Type. In other words, if the answer to event type is "A", dropdown fields will appear for each sub field based on "A".

Comment: You should show the attempt you have made to get this working in the question so we can help show you where you went wrong.

Comment: You need to add example that you worked on. It doesn't mean anything right now.

Comment: For questions that basically ask how to do something in a language, add a code sample that people can work on.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the first select-element of the document has the values
'Plant', 'Animal' and 'Ghost' and the next select-element should change
when the selected value of first ele changes, then this is how we do it:

```
var majorField = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0]
var minorField = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[1]

// Define a dict, mapping each possible value to a function:
majorField.onChangeMap = {
  Plant:  function() { minorField.innerHTML = '<option>Cocoa</option><option>Cocos</option>' },
  Animal: function() { minorField.innerHTML = '<option>Cat</option><option>Cow</option>' },
  Ghost:  function() { minorField.style.visibility = 'hidden' },
}
// When value changes, execute function of dict-map:
majorField.onchange = function(event) {
  event.target.onChangeMap[event.target.value]()
}

// Make sure he minor-field has initially the correct state, by
// executing the mapped function for the major-field's current-value:
majorField.onChangeMap[majorField.value]()
```

Note that this is a very minimal illustration-example for the mapping only, as
one wouldn't set the options as an html-string, and hiding the minorField on
Ghost should be reversed on all other options with `visibility = 'visible'`, here.