# Select and update Option in a list with document.getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, jquery

I m trying to select an option in a list using `document.getElementsByTagName('select')[1].value = 'oop1'`
if it works but it *didn't update* the information related to the selection made

```
    <div class="b">
     <label class="page-text" for="symbol">Symbol:</label>      
     <select class="input-combobox" id="symbol"> 
       <option value="oop1">oop1, Description of it</option>
       <option value="oop2”>oop2, Description of it</option>
    </select>
```

I would like that once the selection is made, the form updates the information related to the selection. If I choose manually I see the update, If I use this function, it selects the option but didn't update.

Comment: Your HTML doesn't look valid ATM, you're missing some end tags, and don't use so-called "smart" quotes in programming, use straight quotes instead

Comment: You question is unclear please elaborate

Comment: I have to choose an option on a webpage, since a choose the first option, the webpage update the information regarding the option I choosed. If I choose second option, I have another information regarding second option. But if I select any option using a script (not my mouse) it select the option but don't update the information.

Comment: Please provide a working code-example as already suggested by CertainPerformance. The script does not work in this example because you're  trying to fetch the second occurring select-element; There's none, just one. If "update the information" means, the selected option should be visible, that works. Otherwise please describe better what "update info" is supposed to mean.

Comment: In response to your comment on the answer below, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44460525/how-to-set-a-default-value-for-a-dependent-field-based-on-the-answer-of-the-pare, HTH.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [0] for getting the first element as there is only one select element. You code was wrong as many tags were incomplete and you were using wrong quotes

```js
var e=document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];
e.options[e.selectedIndex].textContent = 'updated value'
e.value='oop1';
```

```html
<div class="b">
     <label class="page-text" for="symbol" >          
     <select class="input-combobox" id="symbol"> 
       <option value="oop1">oop1, Description of it</option>
       <option value="oop2">oop2, Description of it</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: it is updating but the text of both the options is same so you are not able to see it

Comment: are you trying to change the text of the option tag ??

Comment: I ll give you an exemple, let's say I have a list of currency, I choose eurusd, I should see the price of eurusd. if I select manualy the price will update. If I use a script to select for exemple gbpusd, it will select gbpusd but the price won't update

Comment: thank you, but it only change the name of the option selected to the "updated value"  , so no update, and no selection of an option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189502/discussion-between-ibobo-and-ellipsis).

Comment: @ibobo so what you're actually tying to achieve is to auto-update another select-field when the other changes selection. You might want to update your question accordingly, and please do not paste non-valid code, but a complete example related to the question.

Comment: finally I made it work I hade to just simulate change event on the page :) thank you all for trying )))